# how to Fadein elements when it's visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fadein

I'm using this code I found to fadein elements(with class:hideme) when I scroll to it, but it fades in only when it's fully visible, is there a way I can adjust the code so it fades in as soon as it appears in the browser?

I tried to change the ">" to "=" in this line and it kinda works:

```
if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){
```

but it's not working when i apply to the second elements

thanks!

original link:
http://jsfiddle.net/tcloninger/e5qaD/

here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    /* Every time the window is scrolled ... */
    $(window).scroll( function(){

        /* Check the location of each desired element */
        $('.hideme').each( function(i){

            var bottom_of_object = $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight();
            var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

            /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it it */
            if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){

                $(this).animate({'opacity':'1'},500);

            }

        }); 

    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to check for the top of the object

```
        var top_of_object = $(this).position().top;

        var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

        /* If the top of the object is visible in the window, fade it in */
        if( bottom_of_window >= top_of_object ){

            $(this).animate({'opacity':'1'},500);

        }
```

Updated JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/e5qaD/2727/